# Why does my code perform a double segue?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiviewcontroller, segue

I have on view controller subMenuViewController that links via two different segues called DBSubLegislationSegue and TrafficSegue.

When the user selects a cell from a dynamic table the code should check what row was selected and depending on the cell will perform the correct segue to a new viewController.

When I run the code the app always ends up on the correct view controller however it aways does this by performing two segues, with the first segue always being the Traffic Segue.

Can anyone assist in identifying why this double segue is performed?

```
//populates the table with instances of SubMenuViewCell for each instance filling its label with the correct menuItems
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell =
    self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(
        "SubMenuCell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
        as! SubMenuTableViewCell

    let row = indexPath.row
    cell.subMenuLabel.font =
        UIFont.preferredFontForTextStyle(UIFontTextStyleHeadline)
    cell.subMenuLabel.text = subMenuItems[row]
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.DisclosureIndicator //adds disclosure arrow indicating further info to cell

    return cell
}

//function for handling when a table row is selected by the user.
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    //get the selected row index and save as rowSelected
    let myIndexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()
    rowSelected = myIndexPath!.row
    println(rowSelected)
    if(rowSelected == 0){
        performSegueWithIdentifier("DBSubLegislationSegue", sender: nil)
    }
    if(rowSelected == 1){
        performSegueWithIdentifier("DBSubLegislationSegue", sender: nil)
    }
    if(rowSelected == 2){
        performSegueWithIdentifier("DBSubLegislationSegue", sender: nil)
    }
    if(rowSelected == 3){
        performSegueWithIdentifier("DBSubLegislationSegue", sender: nil)
    }
    if(rowSelected == 4){
        performSegueWithIdentifier("DBSubLegislationSegue", sender: nil)
    }
    if(rowSelected == 5){
       performSegueWithIdentifier("TrafficSegue", sender: nil)
    }
    if(rowSelected == 6){
        performSegueWithIdentifier("DBSubLegislationSegue", sender: nil)
    }
    if(rowSelected == 7){
        performSegueWithIdentifier("DBSubLegislationSegue", sender: nil)
    }
    if(rowSelected == 8){
        performSegueWithIdentifier("DBSubLegislationSegue", sender: nil)
    }
    if(rowSelected == 9){
        performSegueWithIdentifier("DBSubLegislationSegue", sender: nil)
    }
    if(rowSelected == 10){
        performSegueWithIdentifier("DBSubLegislationSegue", sender: nil)
    }
    if(rowSelected == 11){
        performSegueWithIdentifier("DBSubLegislationSegue", sender: nil)
    }

 }

// MARK: - Navigation
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    println(segue.identifier)
    if segue.identifier == "DBSubLegislationSegue" && rowSelected == 0 { //check the row and act appropriately
        let newViewController = segue.destinationViewController    //set the new viewController(new page)
            as! LegislationDBQueryTableViewController
        newViewController.typeOfPage = "All Entries"
    }
    if segue.identifier == "DBSubLegislationSegue" && rowSelected == 1 { //check the row and act appropriately
        let newViewController = segue.destinationViewController     //set the new viewController(new page)
            as! LegislationDBQueryTableViewController
        newViewController.typeOfPage = "Common Law"
    }
    if segue.identifier == "DBSubLegislationSegue" && rowSelected == 2 { //check the row and act appropriately
        let newViewController = segue.destinationViewController     //set the new viewController(new page)
            as! LegislationDBQueryTableViewController
        newViewController.typeOfPage = "Police Procedure"
    }
    if segue.identifier == "DBSubLegislationSegue" && rowSelected == 3 { //check the row and act appropriately
        let newViewController = segue.destinationViewController     //set the new viewController(new page)
            as! LegislationDBQueryTableViewController
        newViewController.typeOfPage = "Police Powers"
    }
    if segue.identifier == "DBSubLegislationSegue" && rowSelected == 4 { //check the row and act appropriately
        let newViewController = segue.destinationViewController     //set the new viewController(new page)
            as! LegislationDBQueryTableViewController
        newViewController.typeOfPage = "Crime"
    }
    if segue.identifier == "TrafficSegue" && rowSelected == 5 { //check the row and act appropriately
        let newViewController = segue.destinationViewController     //set the new viewController(new page)
            as! TrafficSubMenuTableViewController
    }
    if segue.identifier == "DBSubLegislationSegue" && rowSelected == 6 { //check the row and act appropriately
        let newViewController = segue.destinationViewController     //set the new viewController(new page)
            as! LegislationDBQueryTableViewController
        newViewController.typeOfPage = "People"
    }
    if segue.identifier == "DBSubLegislationSegue" && rowSelected == 7 { //check the row and act appropriately
        let newViewController = segue.destinationViewController     //set the new viewController(new page)
            as! LegislationDBQueryTableViewController
        newViewController.typeOfPage = "Civil Order"
    }
    if segue.identifier == "DBSubLegislationSegue" && rowSelected == 8 { //check the row and act appropriately
        let newViewController = segue.destinationViewController     //set the new viewController(new page)
            as! LegislationDBQueryTableViewController
        newViewController.typeOfPage = "Sexual"
    }
    if segue.identifier == "DBSubLegislationSegue" && rowSelected == 9 { //check the row and act appropriately
        let newViewController = segue.destinationViewController     //set the new viewController(new page)
            as! LegislationDBQueryTableViewController
        newViewController.typeOfPage = "Licencing"
    }
    if segue.identifier == "DBSubLegislationSegue" && rowSelected == 10 { //check the row and act appropriately
        let newViewController = segue.destinationViewController     //set the new viewController(new page)
            as! LegislationDBQueryTableViewController
        newViewController.typeOfPage = "Firearms"
    }
    if segue.identifier == "DBSubLegislationSegue" && rowSelected == 11 { //check the row and act appropriately
        let newViewController = segue.destinationViewController     //set the new viewController(new page)
            as! LegislationDBQueryTableViewController
        newViewController.typeOfPage = "Terrorism"
    }

}
```

Comment: In your storyboard, have you ctrl-dragged to create a segue to the new view controller?

Comment: I have control dragged from the dynamic cell to both view controllers with different segues for each.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All fixed.

My error was with the first segue I connected the dynamic CELL to the next view controller however my second segue was connected from the table view itself to the view controller.

By ensuring both were connected from the table view itself the code works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting double segues because the segues you created by control-dragging on the storyboard automatically get called. In other words, since you've created the segues through the storyboard, there's not reason to call `performSegueWithIdentifier`. Assuming you've set the identifiers correctly in the storyboard, the rest of your code will work just fine as is, so you can just go ahead and delete or comment out the contents of your `tableview.didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method.

I suggest using else-ifs in your prepare for segue, like:

```
if segue.identifier == "DBSubLegislationSegue" && rowSelected == 0 {
    //do things
}
else if segue.identifier == "DBSubLegislationSegue" && rowSelected == 1 {
    // do other things
}
//and so on
```